# Is there a way to assign a texture to a button and resize it in the Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-4, image, unreal

I'm attempting to create a main menu for my game and have followed an [easy tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulUO4EN8BG8&feature=youtu.be) to do so. The tutorial doesn't cover assigning textures or images to buttons, so I set out to do this myself.

Assigning the image to the button (I have a 'normal', 'hover', and 'clicked' texture) was rather easy, but the images don't fit.

[image: The button texture.]

Using the 'Image Size' options don't do anything at all and I've got no idea on how to change the image without going back into Photoshop or GIMP and just redoing the whole image to fit the button size.

Is there any way to actually change the size of the image inside the button in Unreal? Or do I just have to suck it up and re-do it?

Comment: "going back into Photoshop or GIMP and just redoing the whole image to fit the button size" - this is generally the correct solution. Stretching an image to fit a size different than the one it was created for can result in unsightly interpolation artifacts that can make your game look low-quality. It's not bad for quick prototypes, but it's probably not a standard you'd want to ship if you can avoid it.

Comment: I thought so. As a follow up, is there an easy way to find out the size of a button in Unreal?

Comment: If you are using some kinds of scale/resize boxes - then your buttons will be resized according to the screen size. However you can specify buttons size if you are adding the directly to the canvas - then you will have transform properties exposed.